# How can I delete the posted question from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I am new to node js, learning it from a course. The course ended and I want to apply some more functionality in my app like I want to **add Delete question** in my app. I'm not getting any idea of how to do it. Kindly suggest me what to do! below I have posted my Model and question API.

**Question Model**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const QuestionSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "myPerson"
  },
  textone: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  texttwo: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  name: {
    type: String
  },
  upvotes: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "myPerson"
      }
    }
  ],
  answers: [
    {
      user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "myPerson"
      },
      text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
      },
      name: {
        type: String
      },
      date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
      }
    }
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = Question = mongoose.model("myQuestion", QuestionSchema);
```

**Question API**

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const jwt = require("../../strategies/jsonwtStrategy")(passport);

//Load person model
const Person = require("../../models/Person");

//Load profile model
const Profile = require("../../models/Profile");

//Load Question model
const Question = require("../../models/Question");

//@type  GET
//@route    /api/questions
// @desc    route for getting  all questions
// @access  PUBLIC
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  Question.find()
    .sort("-date")
    .then(questions => res.json(questions))
    .catch(err => res.json({ noquestions: "No questions to display" }));
});

//@type  POST
//@route    /api/questions/postQuestion
// @desc    route for submitting question
// @access  PRIVATE

router.post(
  "/postQuestion",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    const newQuestion = new Question({
      textone: req.body.textone,
      texttwo: req.body.texttwo,
      user: req.user.id,
      name: req.body.name
    });
    newQuestion
      .save()
      .then(question => res.json(question))
      .catch(err => console.log("unable to post question" + err));
  }
);

//@type  POST
//@route    /api/questions/deleteQuestion/:id
// @desc    route for deleting question
// @access  PRIVATE

//SUGGEST ME HOW CAN DO IT




//@type  POST
//@route    /api/questions/answers/:id
// @desc    route for submitting answers to questions
// @access  PRIVATE
router.post(
  "/newsAnswer/:id",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    Question.findById(req.params.id)
      .then(question => {
        const newAnswer = {
          user: req.body.id,
          name: req.body.name,
          text: req.body.text
        };
        question.answers.unshift(newAnswer);
        question
          .save()
          .then(question => res.json(question))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
);

//@type  POST
//@route    /api/questions/postQuestion/upvote/:_id
// @desc    route for upvoting/unvoting
// @access  PRIVATE
router.post(
  "/upvote/:_id",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id })
      .then(profile => {
        Question.findById(req.params._id)
          .then(question => {
            if (
              //checking if the user who upvoted is in array or not
              question.upvotes.filter(
                upvote => upvote.user.toString() === req.user.id.toString()
              ).length > 0
            ) {
              //if he is found in array we will remove him or unvote
              question.upvotes.pop({ user: req.user.id });
              question
                .save()
                .then(question => res.json(question))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            } else {
              //else if someone is not there we will allow him to upvote
              question.upvotes.unshift({ user: req.user.id });
              question
                .save()
                .then(question => res.json(question))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
          })
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
);

module.exports = router;
```

Please Tell me if you need something more..

Comment: You can use deleteOne() in mongodb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define `delete` endpoint and use `.remove`

```
router.delete(
  "/:id",
  passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
  (req, res) => {
    Question.find({'_id': req.query.id}).remove();
    //OR
    Question.findByIdAndRemove(req.query.id, () => {})
    //rest of code
  }
);
```